# Is it possible for a domain to be faked?

Tags: dns, spoofing, domain

I was talking to PayPal customer service and they were trying to tell me PayPal does not have any third parties, so when I shown them https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/ua/third-parties-list they responded to me that this is not a real paypal site, despite https://www.paypal.com/uk/home being the website for PayPal.

I cannot understand how it cannot belong to PayPal, so I checked and the IP 151.101.129.21 belongs to https://www.paypal.com/uk/home belongs and the IP 23.223.252.174 belongs to https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/ua/third-parties-list, personally I never came accross a way for a domain to be faked but I have seen companies use different IP for different parts of a webiste.

Is it even possible for such a domain to be faked?

Comment: How did you check the IPs? The IP might change over time (even very frequently) or there might be several IPs corresponding to the same domain. However IPs are assigned to domains, the path doesn't count. It doesn't make sense to check the IP of `https://www.example.com/path/to/file`, it only makes sense to check the IP of `www.example.com`

Answer (score 4):

Domains are "faked" all the time. All you need to do is to change the DNS entry. You can do this by setting up a malicious DNS server or to edit the computer's local `hosts` file that acts like your device's internal DNS server.

It is also possible to control a legitimate website to host pages deep in the file structure. So that `www.example.com/flowers/d/g/login/totallyreal/malicious.html` can be any type of page you want or look like any legitimate page.

But I think that's not the issue here. I think there is a simple miscommunication between you. Because of course Paypal "has 3rd parties".

Comment: i didn't know about second example there so it is good to know, i always thought anything after the suffix belonged to the website. The first example sounds similar to how hackers trick the router to load another website however it is the local hosts file on the computer instead. PayPal apologised for misinformation now though so it does seem this website is legit.